# In a list of lists, impose the same length

Tags: haskell

I have this data type, which should represent a table:

```
data R = R [Bool]  deriving Eq -- Row
data T = T [R]     deriving Eq -- Table
```

The problem is that it allows to have table of rows with different length, eg:

```
tab =T [R [True, False, True, True],
        R [False, False, True, False],
        R [False, False, False, True],
        R [False, False]]
```

Is it possible to modify the data definition of `T` to impose that all the `R` elements have the same length?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* do it with `DataKinds`. This may be overcomplicated, though:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs #-}
-- requires 7.4.1, I think

data Nat = S Nat | Z

infixr 0 :.
data R (n :: Nat) where
  Nil :: R Z                     -- like []
  (:.) :: Bool -> R n -> R (S n) -- and (:)

data T (n :: Nat) = T [R n]

-- OK
test1 = T [(True :. True :. Nil), (True :. False :. Nil)]

-- will fail
test2 = T [(True :. True :. Nil), (False :. Nil)]
```

I'd rather recommend @MathematicalOrchids alternative approach using smart constructors.

---

EDIT: What [`DataKinds`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html) do.

The `DataKinds` extension lets the compiler automatically create a new kind other than `*` for each data type one writes, and new types living in this kind from the constructors.

So `Nat`, besides being a simple ADT, also gives rise to a kind `Nat` , and type constructors `Z :: Nat` and `S :: Nat -> Nat`. This `S` is comparable to `Maybe :: * -> *` -- it just doesn't use the kind of all types, but your new kind `Nat`, inhabited only by the representations of the natural numbers.

The point is, that now you also can define type constructors of *mixed* kinds. The classic example for this is `Vec`:

```
data Vec (n :: Nat) (a :: *) where {-...-}
```

which has kind `Vec :: Nat -> * -> *`. Similarly, `T` has kind `T :: Nat -> *`. This let's you use it with a type-encoded constant lenght, and leads to a type error if one two rows of different lenght are put together.

Although this looks extremely powerful, it is in fact restricted. To get the everything out of such representations, dependently typed languages should like [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) should be used.

Comment: I think this is actually quite pretty, I'm surprised that it's so simple. Could you augment your answer with some explanations of why those three language extensions are needed?

Comment: @Frerich With ghc 7.6.1 it's even simpler. The kind `Nat` is built-in and you can use numeric literals at the type level.

Comment: @is7s: That's really nice! For the record, this is explained in the ghc 7.6.1 release notes at [7.9.5 Promoted Literals](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/promotion.html#promoted-literals).

Answer (score 10):

Yup, there's a pretty standard way to achieve that. The price you pay, however, is that you don't get to use the standard list functions (because you won't be using a standard list). The idea goes like this: we'll first have a spine telling how long all the "lists" are, then we'll have the actual lists at the bottom of the spine. You can encode the lengths of the lists in many ways; below, I'll just show how to do it with the simple unary numbering system, but you can of course design more efficient versions with other numbering systems.

```
data BalancedLists_ a as
    = Nil [as]
    | Cons (BalancedLists_ a (a, as))

type BalancedLists a = BalancedLists_ a ()
```

For example, a balanced list containing two length-3 lists would look like this:

```
Cons (Cons (Cons (Nil [(1, (2, (3, ()))), (4, (5, (6, ())))])))
```

There's a wonderful paper extending this technique in a hundred different directions called [Manufacturing Datatypes](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/techreports/cucs-023-99.pdf) by Ralf Hinze.

Comment: What's the advantage of this method over using a list of tuples?

Comment: @is7s This approach lets you choose the length of the tuple at runtime.

Comment: can you please show an example (perhaps in a gist) on how to achieve this?

Comment: @is7s How to achieve what? As for an example, there's one *right there* in the answer!

Comment: I meant an example for how to choose the length at runtime.

Comment: is7s: One short example showing a choice between two different lengths at runtime is `if b then Nil [()] else Cons (Nil [(1,())])`. Google "polymorphic recursion" for examples where the lengths you're choosing between also aren't known statically.

Answer (score 4):

The *list* type represents a container of arbitrary size. You can use a *tuple* to enforce a specific size - but it's only really feasible for "small" sizes. For example:

```
data R = R (Bool, Bool, Bool, Bool) deriving Eq
```

Now each row always contains exactly 4 cells.

If what you actually want is to enforce that the rows can be of *any* size so long as it as *the same* for all rows in the table... that is much more difficult. There are several ways to encode this in the type system, but none of them are especially "simple".

The other alternative is to enforce the condition at run-time, rather than trying to guarantee it at compile-time. You could write a module which defines the row and table types, but hides their definition, and only exposes functions for working with these types which preserve the invariable you want (i.e., all rows equal length).

Comment: `There are several ways to encode this in the type system, but none of them are especially "simple".` - I'd be very interested in learning about one of those ways. :-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe There's a number of ways to do it - but that's an entire _other_ OS question. Oddly, it appears to be one which nobody has asked yet. (Or I'm really bad at searching!)

Comment: I don't get why that'd be another question. This is the main and only focus of this one.

Comment: I think this boils down to encode the length of a list in its type. If a type encodes its length and we put several values of this type in an ordinary list the list type will force the element lists to have equal length.

Comment: @Mog The question asks how to ensure the sublists are all the same length. As I wrote in my answer, the type system is not the _only_ way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way is to use `Data.Array`. One good thing about it is that it allows genuine multidimensional arrays as opposed to arrays of arrays. Just use tuples to index an `Array`.

Comment: How can you restrict the lengths of all rows with `Data.Array`?

Comment: @is7s If you set the array bounds to, say, `(1, 1)` to `(6, 10)` then the array has 6 rows and 10 columns. Every index in that range exists and has a corresponding array element. It's impossible for the rows (or columns) to be of unequal size.

Comment: @is7s: I tried to emphasize that Haskell has both true 2d arrays and arrays of arrays. In the former there is no concept of rows as separate arrays, and so it's not possible even to talk about row lengths :)

Comment: @Nponeccop yes, I'm sorry. I thought you were talking about a compile-time solution.

Comment: It is a compile-time solution.

Comment: It depends on bounds-checking at runtime.

Comment: The original question was: "Is it possible to modify the data definition of T to impose that all the R elements have the same length?". The array approach imposes the same length statically. Out of bound indexing is a different problem from rows having different lengths, and it's not what topic starter asked for.